# iPad debugging on Safari Web Inspector doesn't show all css styles

Tags: ios, css, ipad, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I have my iPad connected to my Mac, I open up 'Develop > iPad Name > Page Name', but I can't seem to inspect & edit the same CSS as I see on Chrome.

Here's a screenshot from Safari Inspect:

[image: See how there's no styles shown for class=order-summary-header?]

And here's chrome screenshot of the same page:

[image: here you can see the css for class=order-summary-header]

At first I just figured Safari Web Inspector is funky that way, but other sites work fine. I.e. I'm able to view & edit the css on other sites as required, but on this particular site I just cant.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Or any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: you can probably click the + button at the bottom to add new style element which will override the current one.

Comment: Yeah that I can do, though the already defined css rules don't show up corresponding to a class.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug. There should not be differences between Chrome and Safari. Please file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/. If you can include a URL or .webarchive from the device (click the Download button in the toolbar), that will help us diagnose the discrepancy directly.